# Sign all needed files in Visual Studio and InstallShield

Tags: visual-studio-2013, installshield, sign

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 professional and InstallShield 2015 Limited Edition.
I have a SafeNet stick and I know how to sign files from the command line.
My Visual Studio solution contains 4 projects: unmanaged Dll, managed Dll (wrapper around the first one), wpf application and an installshield setup project.
My setup output is singleimage (setup.exe file) that contains everything what I need to run and use my application.
The question: how can I define installshield to sign ALL needed files and a setup.exe itself?
Google is not answering my question :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the part of the solution.
1) In Release section of the setup project (in solution explorer) click on the SingleImage section.
2) At the right section you'll see three tabs, the last one is Signing tab. 
The problem is that you need to provide the pfx file.
Creation this file from the SafeNet usb stick is my problem now :)

UPDATE:
My suggestion is to sign the files in post build events in Visual Studio Project properties.
After that sign the setup file and that's all.
I'll try avoid of using InstallShield builder :(